# How to run python function from Django bootstrap Button

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I was tring to understand the working of Django with the Bootstrap button. I was using one of the Django templates, in the index.html file, there is a button defined.

```
 <button type="submit" name="toggle" value="1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-round">Toggle</button>
```

I defined a function in the view.py.

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def mytoggletest(request):
    print("my toogle test script")
    print(request)
```

and this is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    # The home page
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    
    # my test
    path('/', views.mytoggletest, name='toggle'),
   
    # Matches any html file
    re_path(r'^.*\.*', views.pages, name='pages'),
    
]
```

Now when I click on the toggle button in the html page nothing happens.
How can I run my functions in the pythong files from button click on the page in django.

Comment: Is your button in a form? A submit button without a form would do nothing...

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a post request

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def mytoggletest(request):
   print("my toogle test script")
   print(request)
   if request.form['toggle']=="1":
        return redirect(url_for("pages"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have give your button herf like this:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-round" href="{% url '***:***' %}" name="toggle" value="1"> Toggle </a>
```

if you are useing from, you have to add url in your from action.